# How to render an animation in Blender without losing the shading from Viewpoint Shading?

Tags: rendering

I recently started using Blender and am having trouble exporting my animation. I have a 3D rotating animation I'd like to export and am trying to export with Cycles. I am trying to export it so that the image looks like the preview before rendering (Image 1). However, when I render it, the render looks nothing like the preview and all the shading of the black disappears. I have not added any lights, I've only relied on the Viewpoint shading presets (Image 2).

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can do a (top left menu) View >Viewport Render Animation, but you can't have transparency with this render. If you want transparency you need to correctly set your scene, just switch to Rendered Preview mode and put the desired lamps and HDRI so that it looks like the Material Preview

Comment: Oh ok I'll try that thank you. I've been trying to add lamps but it doesn't really do much in terms of showing the actual shading. The black just becomes brighter (more grey) but the shading as seen in the top image isn't shown. What is the best way to maintain the shading with lighting?

Comment: I should note that this object was orignally imported from Adobe Illustrator as an .obj file. It was made in AI using the 3D and Materials window